# remove dash of UUID generated directly on MySQL

Tags: mysql, uuid

I generate `UUID` using `INSERT INTO tbl1 (key, val) VALUES (UUID(), :value)` directly on MySQL using PDO. I don't have any idea how to remove those **-** (dashes) on MySQL side, on PHP side I can simply remove it using `str_replace()`.

Answer (score 21):

```
REPLACE(UUID(),'-','')
```

You don't need the UNHEX, just simply replace the hyphens.

Answer (score 1):

to get decimal value for placing into some integer field use

```
UNHEX(REPLACE(UUID(),'-',''))
```

Comment: Why do I need to `UNHEX` it? My column type is simply just `VARCHAR`

Comment: If you're using the UUID as a PRIMARY KEY, then you'll want to store it as a `BINARY(16)` instead of a `VARCHAR(32)`. It'll really boost your performance when it comes to datasets as small as the 10's of thousands. To do so, you would need to strip dashes and unhex it as in this example. You can read more about UUIDs as Primary Keys from a percona blog [here](https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/12/19/store-uuid-optimized-way/)